# Spring Integration WebFlux.outboundGateway Resequence and Aggregate

Tags: spring-integration

How do we `resequence()` and `aggregate()` the WebFlux output. Kindly suggest.

Below is our flow,

`FileReadingMessageSource` -> `split(fileSplitterSpec())` -> `WebFlux.outboundGateway` -> `resequence()` -> `aggregate()`

```
return Files.splitter()
            .markers()
            .applySequence(true)

.aggregate(aggregatorSpec -> aggregatorSpec.processor(new FileAggregator())
                                            .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
```

**Update:**

```
{Transfer-Encoding=chunked, CUSTOM_HDR=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, sequenceNumber=1, errorChannel=xxxxxxxxx, file_name=Test.txt, originalPayload=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, sequenceSize=0, Connection=keep-alive, file_originalFile=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxTest.txt, xxx=xxxxxxx, file_marker=START, http_statusCode=200 OK, Date=1692201227000, file_relativePath=Test.txt, b3=c3e09ad7ddfaf837-8c44a5b926144a23-0, nativeHeaders={}, xxxxxxxx=0, correlationId=ded2ea9d-4f72-83fd-9897-6b26ed5f4155, id=5eceaea4-7b6d-1d1d-54ab-14b5d7bb1c77, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1692201227936}
```

Comment: Would you mind to share with us what the problem you have just using that `handle(webFlux.outboundGateway())` in the middle of your flow?

Comment: Flow is stuck at the `resequence()`. We are fine without any aggregation, however do require `resequence()`

Comment: Updated with the log of one message right before the 'resequence()`. All messages do have `sequenceNumber` with matching `correlationId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I see your problem. The `FileSplitter` does not populate a `sequenceSize` since it does not know how many lines are there in a file. The `ResequencingMessageHandler` relies on a `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` by default. And exactly that one fails for you since there is no `sequenceSize` to consult with. See if `resequence(resequencer -> resequencer.releasePartialSequences(true))` help you some how. The `groupTimeout()` probably also can help you when left over is there in a group. Not sure, though, why do you need a `resequencer` in a first place since it doesn't look like you are messing up with those lines after splitting some way.

Comment: Thanks Artem got the problem. Each record from the input file has a corresponding output record and we need to maintain the order of the output record in-match with the input file. Since, WebFlux is involved, wouldn't the output be in different order? Pls correct me.

Comment: Yeah... Could be since those returned `Mono` are processed in async manner and therefore reply messages might be produces in out of order.